# eReader SDK in IPad

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch

I need to developed an application for iPad, which shall download eBook from a server and launch eReader application,

i Believe eReader is App provided by amazon for iOS, i.e. whatever user brought form Amazon can read through eReader, i have following question,

1 -- Can i developed an application which invokes eReader app if its there,

2 -- are there any sdk available to access eReader properties, i just wanted to know, how long  this application has been used.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can open other apps using URL schemes. To open the Kindle app:

```
NSString *stringURL = @" kindle:/home";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

2) No, you can't acess any information about other apps using the standard APIs (i.e., without jailbreaking the device).